# MethodInfo.GetMethodBody returns null

Tags: c#, reflection, ninject, castle-dynamicproxy, ninject-interception

I have an `IInvocation` (from `Ninject.Extensions.Interception`) that has a `.Request.Method` that points to a method on a class that I created in my application (so, custom, not anything in core .NET code).  When I call `invocation.Request.Method.GetMethodBody()`, it comes back as `null`.  Why?

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception;
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Infrastructure.Language;

namespace ShortButComplete
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<IMethodHolder>().To<MethodHolder>().Intercept().With<MethodReader>();
            var result = kernel.Get<IMethodHolder>().UhOh();
        }
    }

    public class MethodReader : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var uhoh = invocation.Request.Method.GetMethodBody();
            // The above is null.

            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }

    public interface IMethodHolder
    {
        int UhOh();
    }

    public class MethodHolder : IMethodHolder
    {
        public int UhOh()
        {
            return 4; // Guaranteed random by roll of a d6.
        }
    }

}
```

Looks like it's a Castle DynamicProxy issue:

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
//using Ninject;
//using Ninject.Extensions.Interception;
//using Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Infrastructure.Language;


//IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
//kernel.Bind<IMethodHolder>().To<MethodHolder>().Intercept().With<MethodReader>();
//var result = kernel.Get<IMethodHolder>().UhOh();
var real = new MethodHolder();
var proxy = new ProxyGenerator().CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IMethodHolder>(real, new MethodReader());
var result = proxy.UhOh();
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this with a short but complete program?

Comment: Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Usually `GetMethodBody` returns null for `extern` methods. Is that the case here?

Comment: @JonSkeet:  Will do.  Back in a few!

Comment: @JonSkeet: Short but complete program added.

Comment: @Vache:  Not the case.  Looks like it's probably something to do with ninject interception, so I've added those tags.

Comment: uhm so is the example complete or not? In case it's complete, it can't be about ninject, because the example doesn't contain any ninject proxying stuff at all, right?!

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit:  The example is complete; it's a castle-dynamicproxy issue (that was exposed originally through ninject-interception but can be replicated without ninject).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe method dosent have a body (abstract, interface method, partial, native)?